# Is there a way to diff two Avro GenericRecords in Java to obtain only the fields and values that changed?

Tags: json, avro

I would like to write Java code to diff two GenericRecords saved in memory, both with the same schema. I've been unable to find any libraries or any Apache Avro Javadoc on how to do this.

My desire is to be as efficient as possible, and converting the GenericRecords to JSON, then diffing them, then converting the JSON back to GenericRecord would be undesirable unless that is the only option that exists.

```
protected GenericRecord generateDeltaFieldsOnly(GenericRecord storedRecord, GenericRecord newRecord) 
{

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode storedRecordJson = objectMapper.readTree(storedRecord.toString());
    JsonNode newRecordJson = objectMapper.readTree(newRecord.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just seeing this now...

Just keep both as genericRecords and from the schema just iterate through the fields changing the ones you want.  I sort of do this but use genericRecords from two different schemas and mark up the schema description with keywords that inform the basically dumb  transformer to do the mapping.

```
@Override
public GenericRecord transform(GenericRecord source, GenericRecord reference) {
    GenericRecordBuilder builder = new GenericRecordBuilder(targetSchema);
    buildGenericRecord(builder, source);
    buildGenericRecord(builder, reference);
    return builder.build();
}

private void buildGenericRecord(GenericRecordBuilder builder, GenericRecord genericRecord) {
    String fullName = genericRecord.getSchema().getFullName();
    String targetField;
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : fromFieldToField.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith(fullName)) {
            targetField = entry.getKey().substring(entry.getKey().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            builder.set(entry.getValue(), genericRecord.get(targetField));
        }

    }

}
```

For yours it is much easier if you are using the same schema.

```
for (Field field : storedRecord.getSchema().getFields()) {

        //do your mapping field to field

}
```